# Fireing Android Dialogs from another thread without Message Loop

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, message-loop

In a SurfaceView, I'm dispatching new thread that draws on canvas within standard "LockCanvas-Draw-unlockCanvasAndPost" loop. (note that thread doesn't contains message loop).

How to show Android standard Dialog from that thread?

As thread doesn't have msg loop, following code doesn't work:

```
Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Alert");
builder.setMessage("Stackoverflow!");
builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", null);
builder.show();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? `SurfaceView` extends `View`, so can you make reference to its Handler when setting up the thread?

Comment: I found interesting info on accesing UI thread from other threads:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the second thread a handler that you can send a message on to the first thread that will then show the dialog.

Comment: I found (relatively similar) solution to post DialogBuilding code to "Parent" view via ParentView.post(new Runnable() {...}) method.

Thanx!